# If statement that checking value in current row and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would check if in the 'A' column current row is equal to `red`.
Here the code that I tried, the original Dataframe and Expected output.

Dataframe

```
     A      B     Value
0   red     blue    1.2
1   black   red     1.3
2   green   red     2.2
3   red     brown   0.3
4   red     white   0.9
5   violet  red     1.1
```

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] == 'red':
        df['Value1'] = df['Value']
    else:
        df['Value2'] = df['Value']
```

Output

```
    A      B       Value    Value1  Value2
0   red    blue    1.2      1.2     1.2
1   black  red     1.3      1.3     1.3
2   green  red     2.2      2.2     2.2
3   red    brown   0.3      0.3     0.3
4   red    white   0.9      0.9     0.9
5   violet red     1.1      1.1     1.1
```

Expected Output

```
    A       B       Value   Value1  Value2
0   red     blue    1.2     1.2     NaN
1   black   red     1.3     NaN     1.3
2   green   red     2.2     NaN     2.2
3   red     brown   0.3     0.3     NaN
4   red     white   0.9     0.9     NaN
5   violet  red     1.1     NaN     1.1
```

The `df_iterrows()` method does not return the expected output. Is there a faster method that can do this task?

Comment: `iloc` is for index locations (numerical values starting from 0). `A` appears to be a `loc`. Additionally that would be index location `A` not column `A`.

Comment: Where are you specifying the "current row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check each row of the column to make after this some `#code`:

```py
for row in df.iterrows():
   if t==row['A']:
     #code
```

If you only want to know in which rows of `df['A']` the value of the element is t:

```py
df.loc[df['A']==t, 'A']
```

or

```py
df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('t')
```

**EDIT**

Check if it works for you:

```py
df.loc[df['A']=='red','Value1']=df['Value']
df.loc[df['A']!='red','Value2']=df['Value']
```

Comment: I tried `df.iterrows` but does not return the expected output. Check the post.

Comment: Yes! This is what I am looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `if` statements on `pandas dataframe` as it has different results for different rows.
You need to do:

`df.loc[df['A'] == t, some_col] = some_value`

And it will change the value in `some_col` to `some_value`, in the lines where the value in column `A` is `t`.